# like/unlike button in sp 13 without onloading the page

Tags: like

how to create a like button in a sharepoint page, where on clicking it should increment the likecount which is a column in sp 13 list. on clicking like it should increment the count and on clicking unlike it should decrement the count without onloading the page

Comment: you can make use of reputation.js and use CSOM to create like/unlike functionality.